# Unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$:Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are a Bernoulli($\theta$) with pmf:

$$P(X|\theta)=\theta^X(1-\theta)^{1-X}, \; X \in \{0,1\}$$

Prove or disprove that $\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$

My attempt:

After taking the expectation of $\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})$, I'm getting $E(\bar{X})-E(\bar{X}^2)$. I know that $E(\bar{X}^2)=Var(\bar{X}^2)+[E(\bar{X})]^2$.

If I'm on the right course, how do I calculate $Var(\bar{X}^2)$?
Or Is there an alternative method for this?

Comment: Please reformat your question using proper markup.

Comment: Even computing the variance is not needed to solve this, only that it is nonzero suffices.

Comment: Also, your equality is incorrect. $Var(\bar{X}) = E((\bar{X}-E\bar{X})^2) = E(\bar{X}^2) - (E\bar{X})^2$, so you only need $Var(\bar{X})$, not $Var(\bar{X}^2)$ if you proceed this way.

Comment: @Chester Thanks,that error messed me up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rephrase your current work:  if $w(\boldsymbol X) = \bar X (1 - \bar X)$ is your estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$, then we first observe that $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \theta = \frac{n\theta}{n} = \theta;$$ i.e., $\bar X$ is unbiased for $\theta$.  Consequently,  $$\begin{align*}  \operatorname{E}[w(\boldsymbol X)] &= \operatorname{E}[\bar X] - \operatorname{E}[\bar X^2] \\ &= \operatorname{E}[\bar X] - (\operatorname{Var}[\bar X] + \operatorname{E}[\bar X]^2) \\ &= \theta - \theta^2 - \operatorname{Var}[\bar X] \\ &= \theta(1-\theta) - \operatorname{Var}[\bar X]. \end{align*}$$  If $w(\boldsymbol X)$ were unbiased, we would need the variance of the sample mean to be zero, but this is intuitively impossible, as $\bar X$ is the mean of several nontrivial random variables.  Thus we can see that such an estimator must be biased.

To calculate the actual variance, we rely on the fact that the sample consists of independent and identically distributed observations, hence the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances: $$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X] = \operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \theta(1-\theta) = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}.$$  We can now see that $w$ is biased, but $$w^*(\boldsymbol X) = \frac{n}{n-1} w(\boldsymbol X)$$ is unbiased for $n > 1$.

Comment: Great,it makes perfect sense.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar X, 1-\bar X) &= \mathbb E[\bar X(1-\bar X)] - \mathbb E[\bar X]\mathbb E[1-\bar X]\\
&= \mathbb E[\bar X] - \mathbb E[\bar X^2] - \mathbb E[\bar X] + \mathbb E[\bar X]^2\\
&= \mathbb E[\bar X]^2 - \mathbb E[\bar X^2] < 0
\end{align}
by Jensen's inequality. Moreover,
$$\mathbb E[\bar X]\mathbb E[1-\bar X] = \theta(1-\theta). $$
Hence
$$\mathbb E[\bar X(1-\bar X)] = \operatorname{Cov}(\bar X,1-\bar X) + \theta(1-\theta) < \theta(1-\theta), $$
so that $\bar X(1-\bar X)$ is a biased estimator for $\theta(1-\theta)$.