# $X_i$ follows Bernoulli distribution find UMVUE of $\theta(1-\theta)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3 ...X_n$ be a random sample from Bernoulli
>   distribution with parameter $\theta$.Find UMVUE of $\theta(1-\theta)$.

I know that $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is complete sufficient statistic for our paramenter $\theta$.
I am trying to find out function of T which is a unique unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$.
Now $T\sim Bin(n,\theta)$

$E(T^2)-E(T)^2=V(T)$

$n\theta(1-\theta)+n^2\theta^2-n^2\theta^2=n\theta(1-\theta)$

$\implies\dfrac{1}{n}(T^2-\bar{T}^2)$ is umvue of $\theta(1-\theta)$

> If I have sample size $n=10$ with observations $1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0$
>   obtain the value of this estimator.

Now I am stuck at this point that is $T^2$ is $T^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$ or $T^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2$. Can someone help me and tell at what point I am doing things wrongly?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1403290/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881669/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is $\frac{T}{n} $ where $T=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$.

From your approach that $\operatorname{Var}_{\theta}(T)=\mathrm E_{\theta}(T^2)-(\mathrm E_{\theta}(T))^2=n\theta(1-\theta)$, it follows that an unbiased estimator of $\theta^2$ is $\frac{T(T-1)}{n(n-1)}$. You do not get unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$ directly from this step.

An unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$ is therefore $\frac{T}{n}-\frac{T(T-1)}{n(n-1)}$, which is also the UMVUE.

Comment: If $T \sim Bin(n, \theta)$ then T is random variable right ?

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: estimator I used $\dfrac{1}{n}(T^2-\bar{T}^2)$ if I take expectation I get same result how come mine is not umvue ? $\dfrac{E(T^2)-E(E(T)^2)}{n}=\dfrac{n\theta(1-\theta)+n^2\theta^2-n^2\theta^2}{n}=\theta(1-\theta)$ but umvue is unique. Can you tell me whats wrong ? I didn't get it .

Comment: $\bar T=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}$  sorry I didn't specify that .

Comment: No need to define things like $\bar T$; your notation is confusing. You appear to be doing something like

$E(T^2)-(E(T))^2=n\theta(1-\theta)\implies\left[E(\frac{1}{n}(T^2-(E(T))^2))\right]=\theta(1-\theta)$, and hence concluding that $\frac{1}{n}(T^2-(E(T))^2)$ is UMVUE. This is not correct because $E(T)=n\theta$, so that your proposed estimator is not even a statistic (it depends on the parameter).

Comment: Thanks man I understood my mistake. Now I will use observations in my estimator. $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2=25$ therefor pluging values in my estimator we have  $\frac{5}{10}-\frac{25-5}{90}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{9}=\frac{9-4}{18}=\frac{5}{18}$ can you please confirm is it right ?

Comment: Yes that is the observed value of the estimator.